# Convert JavaScript string to JavaScript literal

Tags: javascript

In Chrome, when you right-click a string on the console, you'll see "copy string as javascript literal" option. This is what I want to have now, in JavaScript.

For example, let's say I have the following text content:

```
console.log('hoge');
```

My question is, how can I get something below from the above?

```
"console.log('hoge');"
```

I want to do this because, I have a mega bytes of webpack-generated long JavaScript content, and for a reason I need to `eval()` the script on an other environment, so I want to copy-and-paste the JavaScript literal text to inside the "eval()". (you may suggest exchanging the data not with the literal but with json (json.stringify/parse), I know, but I just prefer the literal way for now)

So is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: The `Function` prototype has a `toSrting()` method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString

Comment: Just wrap the content generate in two backticks `export const content = \`Your webpack generated content\`.`

Comment: I have an app for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/make-it-a-string. You can install it using `npm install -g make-it-a-string`. It's a command-line app and should work on Mac, Linux and Windows. Just copy the text you want. Then type `make-it-a-string` in a console/terminal. Then paste it where you want it. The app will modify your clipboard content to make it a valid string

Comment: A string in JSON _is_ the same as a string literal. What is the issue here? 

Answer (score 2):

After noting the advice regarding the security weakness inherent in using `eval` (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

You can achieve what you want by enclosing the entire literal code inside back-ticks and using the resulting string as the `eval` argument. back tick quotted strings can include line breaks so you should be able to pass your entire code block inside a single set.

Working snippet.

```js
console.log('hoge');
console.log('another hoge');


eval(`console.log('hoge');
console.log('another hoge')`);
```

Comment: You should escape backticks if present in JS code, otherwise SyntaxError will arise (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have an app for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/make-it-a-string

You can install it by simply using `npm install -g`. Yes, I'm abusing npm to distribute apps but npm is the best cross-platform app store/repo I know of.

The code to convert anything to a valid javascript string is very simple. My app is just 15 lines long (see https://github.com/slebetman/make-it-a-string/blob/main/make-it-a-string).

I'm basically just doing this:

```
const valid_string = JSON.stringify(raw_string,null,4)
```

Yes, that's `JSON.stringify()`. I'm abusing the fact that a string is valid JSON. Basically the string:

```
hello world
```

Has the JSON representation of:

```
"hello world"
```

And `JSON.stringify()` knows how to add the quotes. As an added bonus, `JSON.stringify()` also knows how to escape all other things that need escaping.

For example, the string:

```
hello
"world"
```

Has the JSON representation of:

```
"hello\n\"world\""
```

And again, `JSON.stringify()` knows how to handle this. All the string encoding you need to convert some random string into a valid js string are fully specified by the JSON standard so `JSON.stringify()` is in my humble opinion the correct and valid way to encode js strings.

My full code simply uses the `clipboardy` module to read the text from and then write the formatted text to the clipboard. Here's the full code in case you don't feel like installing it from npm:

```
async function main () {
    const clipboard = (await import('clipboardy')).default;
    
    function result (x) {
        clipboard.writeSync(x);
        console.log(x);
    }

    let raw = clipboard.readSync(); 
    result(JSON.stringify(raw,null,4));
}

main();
```

Obviously there's a chicken-and-egg problem here. To get the string you first need it in a js variable. And if it's already in a variable there's no reason to need it as a string. That's the whole reason I read it from the clipboard.

If instead of the clipboard you prefer to process the string from a file you can do it like this:

```
let raw = fs.readFileSync('my-source-text.js', 'utf8'); 
console.log(JSON.stringify(raw,null,4));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily enclose Javascript in backticks to get a *template literal*:

```
eval(`console.log('hoge')`)
```

But you should also escape backticks inside the Javascript code to handle situations like this:

```
eval(`console.log(`hoge`)`)  // SyntaxError
```

As a solution, you can use this **bash one-liner**:

```
 sed 's/`/\\`/g' | xargs -0 printf 'eval(`%s`)'
```

1. Invoke the command by pressing `Enter`.
2. Paste in the Javascript you want to escape and press `Enter` again.
3. Press `Ctrl+D` to finish input.
4. You will get valid `eval()` function call with escaped template literal on the output.

You can assign this one-liner command to an alias for easy use:

```
 alias js_eval_literal="sed '"'s/`/\\`/g'"' | xargs -0 printf '"'eval(`%s`)'"'"
```

Comment: Situations like? If you create such a situation in code, you should know to escape it.

Answer (score -1):

It feels like you have done it already. You can write that to a file like so

```
fs.writeFileSync(file, 
    "console.log('hoge');"
 );
```

or

```
fs.writeFileSync(file,
        `
       ${ console.log('hoge')}
        ;`
 )
```

back ticks are usually for multiline spacing